# Flatten an array of unknown deep objects, with named properties, in Async/Await JavaScript (or better TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects, flatten

I've already seen that such questions have been answered 1000 times, but I can't get it.

I have an array with various unknown depth objects, only in the property `children` are/might be more objects of the same schema as the parent object.

I need all objects regardless of their dependency in a list.

Here is an example of the raw data:

```json
[
   {
     "id": "root________",
     "title": "",
     "index": 0,
     "dateAdded": 1607859798059,
     "type": "folder",
     "dateGroupModified": 1607859798494,
     "children": [
       {
         "id": "menu________",
         "title": "Lesezeichen-Menü",
         "index": 0,
         "dateAdded": 1607859798059,
         "type": "folder",
         "parentId": "root________",
         "dateGroupModified": 1607859798427,
         "children": [
           {
             "id": "vzj790Oc5ncn",
             "title": "Mozilla Firefox",
             "index": 0,
             "dateAdded": 1607859798427,
             "type": "folder",
             "parentId": "menu________",
             "dateGroupModified": 1607859798427,
             "children": [
               {
                 "id": "YIjZdOQ4I3nz",
                 "title": "Hilfe und Anleitungen",
                 "index": 0,
                 "dateAdded": 1607859798427,
                 "type": "bookmark",
                 "url": "https://support.mozilla.org/de/products/firefox",
                 "parentId": "vzj790Oc5ncn"
               },
               {
                 "id": "cHfBIRuk3-d0",
                 "title": "Firefox anpassen",
                 "index": 1,
                 "dateAdded": 1607859798427,
                 "type": "bookmark",
                 "url": "https://support.mozilla.org/de/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize",
                 "parentId": "vzj790Oc5ncn"
               },
               {
                 "id": "wBPLt_b_UKWN",
                 "title": "Machen Sie mit",
                 "index": 2,
                 "dateAdded": 1607859798427,
                 "type": "bookmark",
                 "url": "https://www.mozilla.org/de/contribute/",
                 "parentId": "vzj790Oc5ncn"
               },
               {
                 "id": "LngszJqD2COI",
                 "title": "Über uns",
                 "index": 3,
                 "dateAdded": 1607859798427,
                 "type": "bookmark",
                 "url": "https://www.mozilla.org/de/about/",
                 "parentId": "vzj790Oc5ncn"
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         "id": "toolbar_____",
         "title": "Lesezeichen-Symbolleiste",
         "index": 1,
         "dateAdded": 1607859798059,
         "type": "folder",
         "parentId": "root________",
         "dateGroupModified": 1607859798494,
         "children": [
           {
             "id": "DnLPkDUWf4k7",
             "title": "Erste Schritte",
             "index": 0,
             "dateAdded": 1607859798494,
             "type": "bookmark",
             "url": "https://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/central/",
             "parentId": "toolbar_____"
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         "id": "unfiled_____",
         "title": "Weitere Lesezeichen",
         "index": 3,
         "dateAdded": 1607859798059,
         "type": "folder",
         "parentId": "root________",
         "dateGroupModified": 1607859798407,
         "children": []
       },
       {
         "id": "mobile______",
         "title": "Mobile Lesezeichen",
         "index": 4,
         "dateAdded": 1607859798081,
         "type": "folder",
         "parentId": "root________",
         "dateGroupModified": 1607859798407,
         "children": []
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I have written a repeating function that goes through the nested elements recursively, however within the repeater function it is not being called again despite the repeat call.

How do I call the custom async function again in TypeScript? recursively

```
  repeater = async (node: any): Promise<any> => {
    const summeryRepeater : any[] = [];
    const children = await this.getChildren(node.id);
    if (children.length >= 1) {
      for (const node of children) {
        summeryRepeater.push(node)
        await this.repeater(node)
      }
    }

    return summeryRepeater
  }
```

```
  // TODO
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  getTreeList = async (): Promise<any> => {

    const summery : any[] = [];

    const node = await browser.bookmarks.get("root________"); // return non children
    summery.push(node[0])

    const children = await this.getChildren(node[0].id); // return non children
    if (children.length >= 1) {
      for (const node of children) {
        summery.push(node)

        // // Repeat start
        const repeater = await this.repeater(node)
        for (const nodeR of repeater) {
          summery.push(nodeR)
        }
        // // Repeat end

      }
    }

    return summery
  }
```

I have been stuck here for days and really need your help. Can anyone give me a hint?

THX, John

Comment: `treeList` or `TreeList`?

Comment: No, sorry for the misunderstanding, one is a variable and the other is a constant. Has nothing to do with the error. But thanks ^^

Comment: Ok. But where are you defining the `treeList` variable?

Comment: It's the return of `getTreeList`. See second Code Block

Comment: "*I have written a repeating function that goes through the nested elements recursively*" - I don't see where you're doing a recursive call in that function?

Comment: i've updated my Post, the repeater won't repeat in the repeater function @_@

Comment: It seems you are ignoring the array that `await this.repeater(node)` results in. Did you want to do something like `summeryRepeater.push(... await this.repeater(node))`?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a task like this doesn't really need async/await or promises - there's nothing asynchronous about flattening a nested data structure.

It's hard to work with the code you posted as its incomplete, so I just made a code sample from scratch that'll take your nested structure and return a flattened version.

```
const flattenStructure = entries => (
  entries
  .flatMap(entry => [entry, ...flattenStructure(entry.children || [])])
  .flat()
)
```

If you call flattenStructure() on your example data above, you'll see that it produces a list of all the objects contained in your structure. It does not modify the objects, so some objects would still have the arrayOfObjects attribute on them that list what their descendants are.

References of functions/concepts used in that code snippet:

- [array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which is the same as [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) followed by [array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (this thing: "...")

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your example doesn't work, I only get the origanie nasted array back with no changes.

I have adjusted the array what I get back as promise above again.

Comment: I've update my question, how can in repeat a function inside itself?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question - could you maybe add what the expected output is of this function if you were to run it against your example raw data?

Comment: Also - you updated your example rawText so have a list of entries as the root element instead of a single element. And now the children are stored under a children key. I've updated the code snippet in my answer to reflect this change (it takes a slightly different function if you're starting with a list of entries then a single entry)

Comment: The Output ist the first code example, the latest question ist: how to run the repeater function in the TypeScript examples. thx

Comment: ... I thought that was the input to the function - sorry :(. My answer is completely wrong then. It'll be hard to help out much though as I don't know what a bunch of those functions are doing in your code snippet - but I'll note one oddities I see: Inside repeater() you're calling `await this.repeater()` without using its return value - did you mean to insert all of the entries in the returned list into summaryRepeater?

Comment: If you're really stuck - try simplifying the task you're trying to do, maybe you've bitten off more than you can chew. Once you've got something simpler working, you can then try to build on it to get your desired final function. Do a bunch of logging (or step through the code) to make sure you really understand how your own code works. I know this isn't the most helpful advice, but I see a lot of newer programmers who get stuck on problems like this for a long time, but never try to subdivide the problem into something they can manage, which is why they stay stuck.